# groupby.mean function dividing by pre-group count rather than post-group count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

So I have the following dataset of trade flows that track imports, exports, by reporting country and partner countries. After I remove some unwanted columns, I edit my data frame such that trade flows between country A and country B is showing. I'm left with something like this:

[My data frame image] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwzx1.png)

My issue is that I want to be able to take the average of imports and exports for every partner country ('partner_code') per year, but when I run the following:

> x = df[(df.location_code.isin(["IRN"])) &
> df.partner_code.isin(['TCD'])]
>
> grouped = x.groupby(['partner_code']).mean()

I end up getting an average of all exports divided by all instances where there is a 'product_id' (so a much higher number) rather than averaging imports or exports by total for all the years.

Taking the average of the following 5 export values gives an incorrect average:

[5 export values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Asm.png)
[Wrong average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJnU8.png)

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, we can `groupby` multiple columns, based on my understanding you want to group by partner, country and year.

The following line would work:

```py
df = df.groupby(['partner_code', 'location_code', 'year'])['import_value', 'export_value'].mean()
```

Please note that the resulting dataframe is has `MultiIndex` index.
For reference, the official documentation: [`DataFrame.groupby` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)